# Do I lose reputation when I repair the enemy artifact vault?

Tags: starpoint-gemini-2

In StarPoint Gemini 2, there are vaults containing artifacts, and the vaults belong to the enemy. But they have to be repaired in order to steal the artifact within. So if I repair the building, will it damage my reputation since it is a enemy's building?

Comment: Elaborate, describe the situation.

Comment: @John the game has some artifact vaults scattered around the map. When you arrive at them, you have the option to repair it. Once you repair, you acquire what is inside it. The thing is, you are "repairing" an enemy structure. So, will I lose reputation for fixing an enemy structure?
The game does not show any message saying I'm losing reputation, but that might be just because they decided to not explicit show it.

Comment: though I have not played the game personally, I would assume that I would not, unless it helps the enemy.

Answer (score 1):

[Starpoint Gemini 2 Wiki](http://starpoint-gemini-2.wikia.com/wiki/Factions)

In the link above, it states

*"Reputation that is gained or lost from doing missions and combating different factions."*

This implies that unless fighting or doing missions for a faction, you will not gain or lose reputation.

In case you are unsure, save before and then open it and if you do not like the outcome, just revert back.